# How to achieve hover effect using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have 3 bullet images.
1 for active, 1 for hover and 1 for the rest links.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#" class="toc selected" rel="2"><img src="images/othersdefdot.png" onclick="funcCaller('fund', 'images/reddot.png', 'local', 'images/othersdefdot.png', 'youthgames', 'images/othersdefdot.png')" name="fund"></a>
```

How to achieve hover effect in this link?

[Check the demo page here](http://girisoft.net/louisa/othersHCS.html)

Comment: Reminds me of the Ubuntu loading dots ;)

Comment: I'd definitely suggest changing to using only an `<a>` tag, with a background image rather than a nested image, and then simply switching the background on `a:hover` and `a:active`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" class="toc selected" onMouseover="showPic1()" onMouseout="showPic2()">
    <img id="link_img" src="/images/othersdefdot.png" />
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function showPic1() {
    document.getElementById('link_img').src = "/images/img1.png";
}

function showPic2() {
    document.getElementById('link_img').src = "/images/img2.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but you can use the `onmouseover` property.

```
<a href="#" class="toc selected" rel="2"><img src="images/othersdefdot.png" onclick="funcCaller('fund', 'images/reddot.png', 'local', 'images/othersdefdot.png', 'youthgames', 'images/othersdefdot.png')" onmouseover="javascriptFunction()" name="fund"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking at the jQuery scrollable here:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/index.html

I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if its just for hover effect, there is no need to use javascript. You could just use css:

```
a img:hover{
   /*change background*/ 
}
```

however if you insist, you could attach event handler `onmousedown` to it. hope that helps.